# SQL: уникальные значения поля для user_id при добавлении новой записи

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать при добавлении новой записи в таблицу уникальное значение столбца dir(инкремент) для конкретного user_id? Если меняется user_id, то dir должен увеличиться на 1.
Например, есть таблица:

```
+-----+------+-----------+
| id  | dir  | user_id   |
+-----+------+-----------+
|  1  | 1    | 55        |
|  2  | 1    | 55        |
|  3  | 1    | 55        |
|  4  | 2    | 22        |
|  5  | 2    | 22        |
|  6  | 2    | 22        |
|  7  | 2    | 22        |
|  8  | 2    | 22        |
|  9  | 3    | 73        |
|  10 | 3    | 73        |
|  11 | 3    | 73        |
+-----+------+-----------+
```

Здесь для user_id = 55 значение dir = 1, для user_id = 22 значение dir = 2 и т.д.

Если в таблицу добавить запись с  user_id к примеру 77, то столбец dir для этого пользователя должен быть равен 4.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы СУБД генерировала значения за вас или вам нужно ограничение, контролирующее уникальность?

Comment: А зачем это нужно ? Как минимум такое поле dir нарушает вторую нормальную форму. Что в свою очередь приведет к каким либо проблемам в будущем и наверняка служит для решения какой то задачи, которую следует решать совершенно иными способами.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Нужно, чтобы СУБД генерировала значения и если есть возможность проверяла уникальность исходя из user_id. Т.е., чтобы для одного user_id одно уникальное число

Comment: @Mike, я хочу сделать каталогизацию картинок для каждого объявления с привязкой к пользователю. Если пользователь загрузит картинки, то они попадут в одну папку. Для другого пользователя будет другая папка и т.д.

Comment: Почему бы для папки не воспользоваться самим id пользователя. Если все таки должно быть другое число - то ему незачем дублироваться для каждой картинки, ему следует храниться в таблице пользователей. Что бы конкретное значение было только в одной записи зависящей от пользователя

Comment: @Mike На самом деле описанную задачу я специально упростил для наглядности. Вместо id пользователей есть сгенерированное случайное число для идентификации пользователя, которое записывается в куку. При добавлении картинки мы проверяем, были ли загружены картинки этим пользователем. Если нет, то создаем директорию и загружаем. Директорию хотелось бы создавать в определенной последоательности от того, что уже есть, т.е. по-порядку.

Comment: Тогда у вас должна быть таблица "Директории" в которую будет добавляться запись если ее еще нет. И в этой таблице кроме id директории рядом может лежать тот самый id из куки. А вообще порядковое назначение имен директорий не безопасно. Принято давать настолько случайные имена, что бы их нельзя было предсказать и обратиться по имени папки к чужим картинкам до их публикации, например.

Answer (score 2):

> возможно ли реализовать при добавлении новой записи в таблицу уникальное значение столбца dir(инкремент) для конкретного user_id?

Да, возможно. Для этого необходимо, чтобы а) первичным индексом таблицы была совокупность полей (user_id, dir) - именно в таком порядке б) таблица была создана на движке MyISAM.

Подробности см. в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Для других движков используйте решения программного присвоения значения.

Comment: офигеть! и Вы всё это время скрывали такое?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table (id,dir,user_id) 
select new_id, max(dir) + 1 as ndir, new_user_id
from table;
```

Comment: Не прокатит. Надо же еще проверить наличие такого пользователя и если он есть то выдать старый dir

Answer (score 0):

учитывая комментарий выше можно проверять есть ли запись для добовляемого пользователя если есть брать его dir если нет то максимум +1

```
insert into table (id,dir,user_id)
select new_id, 
       case when user_id is null 
          then (select max(dir)+ 1 as dir from  t) 
          else t.dir  end as dir,
       new_user_id
from t
where user_id = new_user_id;
```

Comment: И опять не прокатит. Если записей с таким пользователем несколько - то и вставлено будет несколько. Надо бы ограничить limit 1. Хотя лучше было бы написать `select new_id, coalesce(max((user_id=new_user_id)*dir), max(dir)+1, 1), new_user_id from Table` в таком варианте предусмотрено и несколько записей и их отсутствие и даже полное отсутствие записей в таблице, которое вернет NULL на max() и +1 для которого так же даст NULL. Но такого все равно делать не стоит ибо это нарушает 2НФ и ни к чему хорошему не ведет